# how to get only data from fetch

Tags: javascript, svelte

I try to get only the data of my fetch request but when i go out of my function there is a promise arround.

I try to fetch an API for starting a store in svelteJS but I'm wrong.

```
import {writable} from "svelte/store";

const getPokedex = async function () {
    let pokedexData
    await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100&offset=0')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            pokedexData = createPokedex(data)
        })
    return pokedexData
}

const createPokedex = function (data) {
    let pokedex = writable(data)
    ...
}

export const pokedex = getPokedex();
```

## SOLVED:

```
const getPokedex = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100&offset=0');
    const data = await response.json();
    let pokedex = data.results
    return createPokedex(pokedex);
}
export const pokedexStore = await getPokedex();
```

Comment: `async` function returns a Promise --- that's what it's designed to do - you can `export const pokedex = await getPokedex();` - also, the way you've written that getPkedex function is odd ... there's hardly ever a reason to use both async/await AND .then - that can be written simply like `const getPokedex = () => fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100&offset=0').then(response => response.json()).then(createPokedex);` - note, no async/await there (I find this cleaner than using async/await with such simple code)

Comment: I didn't understand it in that way.

Tjank you for your help :)

Comment: really? that's basically your code written without redundant async/await

Comment: I have tried with ``then`` but I have an error but the answer with async await have passed

Comment: you probably wrote it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of `async/await` and try to not use `then/catch` while using `async/await` this will make your code more clean, readable, easy to work with

```
const getPokedex = async function () {
  const response = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100&offset=0");
  const data = await response.json();
  return createPokedex(data);
};
```

this code will return the data you just have to wait for the promise using `await`

`const pokedex = await getPokedex();`

Comment: `this code will only return the data without the promise` ... no, this code will return a `Promise`, since the function is `async`  - that's why you have to await it at the end

Comment: Thanks didn't meant that